Filter rows by condition on columns with certain names
I have a dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": ["ID1", "ID2", "ID3",
                                "ID4", "ID5"],
                   "Item": ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3",
                                    "Item4","Item5"],
                   "Catalog1": ["cat1", "1Cat12", "Cat35",
                                    "1cat3","Cat5"],
                   "Catalog2": ["Cat11", "Cat12", "Cat35",
                                    "1Cat1","2cat5"],
                   "Catalog3": ["cat6", "Ccat2", "1Cat9",
                                    "1cat3","Cat7"],
                   "Price": ["716", "599", "4400",
                                    "150","139"]})

I need to find all rows, that contain string "cat1" or "Cat1" in any column with name starting with Catalog (the number of these columns may vary, so I can't just list them).
I tried:
filter_col = [col for col in df if col.startswith('Catalog')]

df_res = df.loc[(filter_col.str.contains('(?i)cat1'))]

But I get mistake:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'str'

filter_col is just a list of column names so you can't call .str.contains() directly on it like it's a pandas series

In your code, filter_col is a list. You can't use str with it.
You can make use of pandas functions to do the operations faster.
Here's the code to solve it:
import pandas as pd

# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": ["ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5"],
                   "Item": ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4","Item5"],
                   "Catalog1": ["cat1", "1Cat12", "Cat35", "1cat3","Cat5"],
                   "Catalog2": ["Cat11", "Cat12", "Cat35", "1Cat1","2cat5"],
                   "Catalog3": ["cat6", "Ccat2", "1Cat9", "1cat3","Cat7"],
                   "Price": ["716", "599", "4400", "150","139"]})

# Define the search strings
search_strings = ["cat1", "Cat1"]

# Filter the DataFrame
filtered_df = df[df.filter(like='Catalog').apply(lambda row: 
row.str.contains('|'.join(search_strings), case=False).any(), axis=1)]

print(filtered_df)


I don't know how big your original data is, but for the code below:
df.loc[[row for row in df.index if df.loc[row].str.contains('(?i)cat1').sum()]]

You get the result:
    ID      Item    Catalog1    Catalog2    Catalog3    Price
0   ID1     Item1   cat1        Cat11       cat6        716
1   ID2     Item2   1Cat12      Cat12       Ccat2       599
3   ID4     Item4   1cat3       1Cat1       1cat3       150

The problem I see is that you want to use the .str method for the list directly, and that causes the error. You can, however, use it on the pd.Series as in my code.

Probably you can try pd.Series before using str.contains, e.g.,
df[list(map(lambda x: any(pd.Series(x).str.contains("(?i)cat1")),df.filter(like = "Catalog").values))]

such that you will obtain
    ID   Item Catalog1 Catalog2 Catalog3 Price
0  ID1  Item1     cat1    Cat11     cat6   716
1  ID2  Item2   1Cat12    Cat12    Ccat2   599
3  ID4  Item4    1cat3    1Cat1    1cat3   150


A short one liner that searches every column.
df[df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('cat1', case=False)).any(axis=1)]

Result:
    ID   Item Catalog1 Catalog2 Catalog3 Price
0  ID1  Item1     cat1    Cat11     cat6   716
1  ID2  Item2   1Cat12    Cat12    Ccat2   599
3  ID4  Item4    1cat3    1Cat1    1cat3   150

